# Is it possible to find a crashed ship before first visiting a Transmission Tower?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Obviously as you travel around the planet, you'll find a lot of different structures - observatories, trading posts, mining facilities, mineral storage, and more. However, I've never personally found a crashed ship before first successfully solving the puzzle at a nearby transmission tower.

This begs the question - Is it possible to randomly encounter crashed ships? Or is the transmission tower "pre-quest" required to spawn the crashed ship?

(I suspect solving the transmission tower puzzle is required, since that would explain why the crashed ship you find is *always* ±1 item slot compared to your current ship... but I don't have any concrete proof.)

Comment: As a side note you can use the same transmission tower as many times as you'd like. It will always have the same question/answer and will almost always mark a new crashed ship. This way you can use the transmitter to find 5-10 ships or more before going out and finding them.

Comment: What the heck kind of quality control do the manufacturers have for these ships, if they're always crashing like this?

Comment: @VanBuzzKill I can't confirm this. Not even after hours of in-game time or loading a game etc. I can use a Trasmission Tower for a second time.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill Are you sure about that? I just tried last night, and I was definitely only able to use the tower once. I have heard that this might be a glitch specific to Gek transmission towers, but I don't know the specifics.

Comment: @MageXy I've done it myself twice and it's been awhile but it might've been in Gek towers as you mentioned. At least one of them for sure was but I can't remember the other time.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill Just to follow up... I tested over the weekend, Gek towers definitely allow multiple uses while others do not. I'm guessing this is a bug... one that I will abuse to get an upgraded ship, heh.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. They will not be marked but you can see them as you fly over the surface of the planet.

Comment: Can confirm. Happened to me last night.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to find Crashed Ships on the Planets surface without visiting a Transmission Tower, but it would be a much quicker process to Visit the Transmission Towers than to try and stumble across them at random.